# perl two consecutive back ticked shell command do not run

Tags: perl, backticks

I am trying to write perl script for managing amazon ec2 instances. In part of my code, I have two shell commands, and when I invoke them, the first runs but not the second. I cannot seem to find a good explanation for this. Here is the code:

```
$run_instances = 'ec2-run-instances ami-8e1fece7 -k mykey -t t1.micro';
$outp = `$run_instances`;
$outp =~ /INSTANCE\s+(i-\w+)\s/;
$instance_id = $1;
$describe_instances = "ec2-describe-instances $instance_id";
$outp = `$describe_instances`;
$outp =~ /(ec2-(\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+).\S+)/;
```

The problem is `$outp` here has the output of `$run_instances`. For some time I could not understand why I was getting the wrong output; then I realised that `$describe_instances` command does not run.

I looked at the value of `$describe_instances`, called that from the Linux shell, and it worked fine. I called it from another Perl script, and it worked fine.

Then I gave `$outp` the output that is captured when `$run_instances` runs (`$outp = "INSTANCE ......"`). It worked, so I got the idea that somehow when these two commands run consecutively the second does not run.

One more thing to note is that when I put above code in a loop every time `$run_instances` works but `$describe_instances` does not.

I would be really happy if you could provide some light on this :)

Thank you

Comment: Add some debugging, e.g. prefix `$describe_instances` with `set -x; `

Comment: I'm glad my answer helped. What was the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program has a few red flags. I discuss them below and at the end suggest a better way to write your code.

#### Red Flag 1

The code from your question attempts to execute external commands with backticks and assumes success. You should *always* check the status of any call to the operating system. A failed [`` `$command` ``](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2fSTRING%2f)—also known as [`qx//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#qx%2fSTRING%2f) or [`readpipe`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readpipe.html)—makes itself known in one or more ways depending on whether the command executed and failed or whether attempted execution of the command failed:

- The value of the special variable [`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%3f) is non-zero.
- In cases of failed execution

  - the special variable [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24!) contains a description of the failure.
  - the operator returns the undefined value in scalar context or the empty list in list context.

With Perl, `` `$command` `` executes a subshell in order to execute `$command`, so the subshell may be the program that executes and fails, *e.g.*, for bad command syntax.

Exactly one command in the example below succeeds on my machine.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @commands = (
  "bad syntax (",
  "does-not-exist",
  "/etc/passwd",
  "perl --no-such-option",
  "perl -le 'print q(Hello world)'",
);

foreach my $c (@commands) {
  print "Capturing output of command $c...\n";
  my $output = `$c`;

  if ($? == 0) {
    print "  - command executed successfully!\n";
  }
  elsif ($? == -1) {
    print "  - command failed to execute: \$!=$!\n";
  }
  else {
    print "  - command exited with status " . ($? >> 8) . "\n";
  }

  print "  - value of \$output is ",
        (defined $output ? "" : "un"), "defined\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Capturing output of command bad syntax (...
sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
  - command exited with status 2
  - value of $output is defined

Capturing output of command does-not-exist...
Can't exec "does-not-exist": No such file or directory at ./runcmds line 16.
  - command failed to execute: $!=No such file or directory
  - value of $output is undefined

Capturing output of command /etc/passwd...
Can't exec "/etc/passwd": Permission denied at ./runcmds line 16.
  - command failed to execute: $!=Permission denied
  - value of $output is undefined

Capturing output of command perl --no-such-option...
Unrecognized switch: --no-such-option  (-h will show valid options).
  - command exited with status 29
  - value of $output is defined

Capturing output of command perl -le 'print q(Hello world)'...
  - command executed successfully!
  - value of $output is defined
```

#### Red Flag 2

Note for example the line of output

```
Can't exec "does-not-exist": No such file or directory at ./runcmds line 16.
```

I didn't write the code that generated this warning. Instead, it happened automatically because I enabled the warnings pragma with the line `use warnings`. Had you enabled warnings, Perl would have already given you at least a hint about the cause of your problem, so I assume you didn't enable warnings.

This is another red flag. Warnings are there to help you. Always enable them for any non-trivial program.

#### Red Flag 3

Finally, you're using regex capture-variable `$1` unconditionally, and this habit will lead to surprising bugs when the match fails and you get a captured value from different match. You should always wrap uses of `$1`, `$2`, and friends inside a conditional, *e.g.*,

```
if (/pa(tte)rn/) {
  do_something_with $1;
}
```

#### Recommended Fixes

Near the top of your code just after the shebang line, you should immediately add the line

```
use warnings;
```

I'd also recommend

```
use strict;
```

but that will likely require more work to clean up your code. We're here to help you understand and overcome any issues you find in that worthwhile effort.

Use `output_of` below to capture a command's output or die with an appropriate diagnostic.

```
sub output_of {
  my($cmd) = @_;
  my $output = `$cmd`;
  return $output if $? == 0;

  if ($? == -1) {
    die "$0: $cmd failed to execute: $!\n";
  }
  elsif ($? & 127) {
    my $signal = $? & 127;
    my $core = ($? & 128) ? ", core dumped" : "";
    die "$0: $cmd died with signal $signal$core\n";
  }
  else {
    die "$0: $cmd exited with status " . ($? >> 8) . "\n";
  }
}
```

The section of code from your question becomes

```
my $output;
$output = output_of 'ec2-run-instances ami-8e1fece7 -k mykey -t t1.micro';
if ($output =~ /INSTANCE\s+(i-\w+)\s/) {
  my $instance_id = $1;

  $output = output_of "ec2-describe-instances $instance_id";
  if ($output =~ /(ec2-(\d+-\d+-\d+-\d+).\S+)/) {
    print "$0: found instance $2\n";  # or whatever
  }
  else {
    die "$0: no ec2-IP in ec2-describe-instances output:\n$output";
  }
}
else {
  die "$0: no INSTANCE in ec2-run-instances output:\n$output";
}
```

With these changes, your code will supply on the standard error diagnostics for all failure modes in processing output from `ec2-run-instances` and `ec2-describe-instances` instead of leaving you to wonder what went wrong.

Comment: IPC::System::Simple makes this...simple.

Answer (score 1):

Is $outp defined or undefined after the:

```
$outp = `$describe_instances`;
```

Have you verified that $instance_id is set to what you expect?
What are the values of $! and $? after the non-working backtick command?
Is anything being written to stderr by the non-working command?

Comment: $instance_id contains exactly what i expected. i print $! and $? but i got no output. after $outp=`$describe_instances`; $outp has the same value it got after $outp =`$run_instances` . it is like somehow this line skips

Comment: is it possible that perl goes to the next line of execution without waitin complete execution of the shell command? because it takes 7 8 secs for the $run_instances command to return.

Comment: I wouldn't think that likely.  You're best off making your code more rigorous as described by Greg Bacon and seeing if that gives you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is this line:

```
$instance_id = $1;
```

`$1` is a global variable. One should never use `$1` et al untested, since it:

> Contains the subpattern from the
>   corresponding set of capturing
>   parentheses from the **last successful**
>   pattern match

(from [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html))

In other words, it is not overwritten if there is no match. What you might do is something like this:

```
die $! unless ( $outp =~ /INSTANCE\s+(i-\w+)\s/ );
$instance_id = $1;
```

I try never to use `$1` untested, and of course there are many ways to make sure it comes from the right place.